# CSS transition is not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to build a landing page, however my page fade in is not working on chrome. (It works well on Firefox, I had a few friends check). I cant figure out what is going on.

I'am using this for the fade

```css
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s 2s;
}

body.fade-out {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script>
  document.body.classList.add('fade-out');
</script>
```

I checked caniuse.com and it should all be fine. Any ideas whats up? Any fixes in mind?
link to the site : aidenec.com

Edit: not working on safari

Comment: where you are putting the script ? it should be at the end the page

Comment: In chrome, if you wait for the document to finish loading before adding that class, it will work just fine. either window `load` event or document `DOMContentLoaded` event - as to why? Who knows? Google does what google does :p